# Development environment with Docker and deploying to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, laravel, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm writing a PHP application and want the development environment to be a Docker container. To do that, I've created a `Dockerfile` in the root of my project that installs all the packages required by my application, copies over configuration files to the container and then installs my application.

This is working fine, but now I need to tell my PHP application what environment it's in, either `development` or `production`. This is also easy, I can just add this to my `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV environment development
```

Now when I build my image, my PHP application runs in `development` mode. Great, now I can build my application inside a Docker container!

But what happens when I want to deploy this application to a production server (AWS Elastic Beanstalk, to be specific)? If I've specified in my `Dockerfile` that the environment is `development`, will my application not run in development mode when it's deployed to Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the environment variable is a good way to do it; however, by doing it in the Dockerfile you're setting it for any containers derived from that image. What you really want to do is set it on a container-by-container basis. The way to do that is by setting it when you run the container:

For development:

`docker run --env environment=development my-image`

And for production:

`docker run --env environment=production my-image`

Note that this will work even if you set the environment variable in your Dockerfile - variables set with `docker run --env` will override the values set in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Now that I look it up the --env flag I see it was right there in the documentation... I must've skipped right past it. :/ Thank you! :)